# Why is Application Insights Performance Counter Collection causing high CPU usage

Tags: monitoring, azure-application-insights

Logging performed by our Performance Team has indicated that this line specifically, is killing our CPUs

Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector!Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.Implementation.PerformanceCounterUtility.ExpandInstanceName()

One theory was the the regexes used to identify Perf Counters in the library are recursing

https://adtmag.com/blogs/dev-watch/2016/07/stack-overflow-crash.aspx

I've inspected the Perf Counter names and nothing looks particularly out of kilter regarding the names and the regexes should have no trouble chewing over them.  Certainly for large periods of time there are no issues whatsoever.

I've now turned on Applications Insights Diagnostic Logging in an attempt to observe the issue (in a test environment)

Has anyone else observed this, how can we mitigate this?
**We have ensured DeveloperMode is NOT set to on.**

Comment: Has anyone else observed this -> I didn't

Comment: Which counters are you collecting specifically? Is it just the default set, or have you configured something custom? ExpandInstanceNames does a lot of work to determine the instance of the counter which pertains to the application's process, so in case you have custom counters configured, you can potentially speed things up by avoiding "instance placeholders" such as ??APP_WIN32_PROC?? and specifying concrete instance names.
Also, what's the CPU usage pattern you're seeing? Is it high all the time, or are there spikes? ExpandInstanceNames should only be invoked once every 5 minutes or so.

Comment: @ZakiMa,  Yeah we have a bunch of NServiceBus custom counters.   CPU usage is absolutely fine and then 4/8 cores on a box will go mad at 100% with that method looking like the villain of the piece.  But it doesnt seem recoverable.  Its a concern as we are just about to enter a peak period and the tin which this is occurring on needs plenty of headroom.

Comment: @tokaplan answered below. Above question was from him as well - at the time he didn't have enough reputation points to ask himself =)

Comment: I have an answer will post soon.

Comment: Hi, could you please share if you mitigated this? I`m running into similar issue (I guess).

Comment: For me it looks like not-synchornized access to dictionary in PerformanceCounterUtility class. Do you have the same observation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this answer most likely won`t be usable now as AppInsights 2 code is much improved, but in my case it was double call AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(). It adds collector each time this method is called, and due to lack of synchronization inside perf counter collector code it creates CPU spikes.

So avoid calling multiple times AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry, or use AppInsights 2.x. (and the best thing is to do both).

Comment: This is exactly what my edit was going to say!  We were registering it 4 times I think causing alot of spiking!

Answer (score 1):

Do the counters you're collecting utilize instance placeholders in their names? If the instance name is known at build time, getting rid of placeholders may significantly improve performance. For instance, instead of

```
\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\% Processor Time
```

try using

```
\Process(w3wp)\% Processor Time
```

Also, how many counters are you collecting overall?